# Confusion about dart toStringAsFixed

Tags: flutter, dart, rounding

Can someone explain to me why these code are producing these results?

```
2.385.toStringAsFixed(2); // 2.38
1.385.toStringAsFixed(2); // 1.39
```

I'm genuinely confused and extremely curious what leads to this behaviour.
Encountered this issue when I'm doing rounding for currency calculation for varying decimal places. I got the same result with

```
double.parse(NumberFormat('#.00').format(2.385)); // 2.38
double.parse(NumberFormat('#.00').format(1.385)); // 1.39
```

Comment: I guess another case of [Floating Point Math](https://0.30000000000000004.com/)

Comment: That's my guess as well but the results are very consistent across multiple executions that I'm hoping there's a better answer to this

Comment: What's wrong with it being consistent?

Comment: Nothing wrong with being consistent. It just made me more curious. If there's more randomness to it then I would have chalked it up to floating point and move on

Comment: Imprecision does not mean randomness. You can run a program that has certain floating number 1000x on the same platform and it will result the same representation. That's why the [Floating Point Math](https://0.30000000000000004.com/) has example results for each language.

Comment: This is due to 2 things. 1. Floating point arythmetic, what you think is 1.38 is NOT exactly 1.38 in JS since its type Number uses floating point representation.
2. How the rounding is made which again depends on JS and the default rounding chosen.
For more options you can use specialised libraries like Mathjs

Comment: "If there's more randomness to it then I would have chalked it up to floating point and move on" Floating-point is deterministic, not random.  That (infinitely) many decimal numbers cannot be exactly represented in binary is fact; randomness is not involved.